# How to convert Json string into Json Array in Android Studio Java

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley

I have a Json String like below

```
["Monday","Tueday","wednesday","Thuesday","Friday","Saturday"]
```

What I want to do is send this Json String to a web server using the android studio volley library.

SO I keep getting this error

```
 com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

The string cannot be converted to JsonArray.

**So I have 2 questions I need help with.**

My first is how to convert string to JsonArray. For example below String.

```
 ["Monday","Tueday","wednesday","Thuesday","Friday","Saturday"]
```

My second question is about passing this Jason Array (once we create) to a web server. I was researching about the Hashmap but I don't know how to send the JsonArray in Hashmap.

I had a go with below code, but it did not work.

```
@Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return super.getParams();
        }
```

I don't know how to send JsaonArray in hashmap.

So Overall, I would like to send this above string to web server.

Answer (score 0):

Supose that the name of string is myString.

```
rString = myString.replace('[','');
rString = rString.replace(']','');
rString = rString.replace('"','');
String split[] = rString.split(',').
```

Now you have an array called split with every position is a day.

Comment: Will this be a JsonArray or nor normal Java array

Comment: Normal java array, then u can parse it to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This is for frist question

Use that

```
JSONArray yourJsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject(yourJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer to first question:

I think it's not the exact response from the server, and there's a HTML `<br>` tag in the response.

because the line `Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be...` clearly contains string `<br`, try replacing the HTML tags and/or decoding/unescaping the HTML tags to plain text, AND then you can convert that plain JSON text to *JSONArray*.

this snippet might help you out with decoding the response:

```
String parsedReponse = Html.fromHtml(serverResponse).toString()
if (parsedReponse != null) parsedReponse = parsedReponse.trim();
```

---

### Answer to second question:

check out OkHttp3 and Retrofit libraries, they're pretty popular and amazing.

those can help you send POST data to your server

---

**hope that helped you :)**